# Is the unit of VmData in proc/[pid]/status stored elsewhere?

Tags: linux, process

Is it safe to assume that the VmData, VmStk and VmExe (Size of data, stack, and text segments) 
are always expressed in kBs ? Is this unit stored somewhere or are these values the only places where unit information is stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any documentation that says for certain it is in kBs, however, it is my best guess that it is. Here are some programs I ran across that depend on it being in kBs:

https://github.com/pmav/procvm/blob/master/procvm.sh

Look at the first code here:
http://locklessinc.com/articles/memory_usage/

Search for "Checking memory from a serial C program" here:
http://www.umbc.edu/hpcf/resources-tara/checking-memory-usage.html